# Website sticks out of the window on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive

it's been few hours that I am looking for the answer to my problem and I am starting to desesperate. I hope you could help me ! 
I am developping a personal website and I am working on the responsive. I don't know why, but on mobile, I can horizontally scroll, the body (or whatever this is) sticks out of the window. I've tried to place some `box-sizing : border-box` because I thought it would resolve it then I check 2x times my entirely code, trying to delete or add some elements but still no good result.

Given that I don't know where the problem is, I think it is easier if I provide you the url : [right here](http://nicolas-werner.com). (Use the web developer mode of your browser to see the website on a mobile way so you can see my problem)

Hope you can help me, I haven't any other idea of what to do...

Thanks !

Comment: Try adding `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `<body>`

Comment: Wow... I just don't know how to thank you, it works ! You just saved my life haha a big thank you !